# setState update object property React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm using a increment and decrement button,

I'm directly using the code instead of adding the package - here is the [code link](https://github.com/shrilakshmishastry/react-native-increment-decrement-button/tree/main/RnIncrementDecrementBtn)

My Array Format

```
[
{
  "id": "0.287635530963835",
  "item_name": "Item 2",
  "item_price": "56",
  "item_qty": "1"
}, {
  "id": "0.625240011345925",
  "item_name": "Item 23",
  "item_price": "23",
  "item_qty": "1"
}
]
```

The IDBtn

```
items.map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <View key={item.id}>
                                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.mainitems} >
                                        ...
                                        <View style={styles.mainitems3}>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                                ...
                                                <IDBtn val={item.item_qty} minVal={1} /> //<---here
                                            </View>
                                            ...
                                        </View>
                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                </View>
                            )
                        })
                    }
```

**SO i want to update this item `item_qty` if increment or decrement inside my setState, but don't know how to do this**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first summarize how I have understood your issue. You have a state called `items` that contains an array containing objects with a property named `item_qty` which is a number. You want to iterate over this state array and create a button for each of these objects. The button contains the exact same code as provided from the component of the Github repository you have provided in your question. You have renamed this button to `IDBtn`. This button provides the functionality to `increment or decrement` a number.

Now, since you have an array in your state, you need this component to update the individual values inside that state without changing the others.

If you look closely at the component, you will notice that it uses an inner state to handle this functionality.

> However, the component also provides a callback function named `handleClick` which will pass the updated value back to the parent component (thus you receive the either incremented or decremented value).

We know need to update our parent state object using this callback function.
I am not sure why you are wrapping `IDBtn` inside a `TouchableOpacity` since you are not using its onPress callback. If you want to have the visual effect it provided, I would suggest that you change this in `IDBtn` directly. I have removed it here.

Notice that we provide the index to `handleClick` in order to update the correct value.

```js
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([])

// fetch data and setItems initially
...

// notice  that onClick will receive the udpated value from the component 
// and we pass the index to it as well in order to update the correct 
// value for our inner state
function onClick(val, index) {
   setItems(previous => previous.map((item, idx) => index === idx ? {...item, item_qty: val} : item))
}

items.map((item, i) => {
    return (
        <View key={item.id}>
            <View style={styles.mainitems} >
              ...
                 <View style={styles.mainitems3}>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                       ...
                       <IDBtn handleClick={(val) => onClick(val, i)} val={parseInt(item.item_qty)} minVal={1} />
                     </View>
                       ...
                 </View>
         </View>
     )
 })
}
```

Comment: Thanks You David for your deep explanation